# Combine multiple count queries to a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL, I have a set of queries which returns the count values from different tables with different conditions like below

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT GroupUserID) AS KnownUsers 
FROM Table A 
WHERE ...

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT GroupUserID) AS UnKnownUsers 
FROM TableB  
WHERE (a different condition)

SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ManagerID) AS Managers, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT LeadID) AS TeamLeads 
FROM
    TableX  
WHERE 
    (condition)
```

Is there any way or query that can be used to combine all the 3 SQL queries into a single one which will return 4 columns?

```
  KnownUsers    UnKnownUsers   Managers    TeamLeads
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    SELECT  (select COUNT(distinct GroupUserID) as KnownUsers from Table A WHERE ...) as KnownUsers ,   

    (SELECT  COUNT(distinct GroupUserID) as UnKnownUsers from TableB  WHERE (a   different condition)) as UnKnownUsers,

    (SELECT  COUNT(distinct ManagerID) from TableX  WHERE (condition)) as Managers, 
 (SELECT  COUNT(distinct LeadID) as TeamLeads from TableX  WHERE (condition)) as TeamLeads
```

Comment: I think you should separate the elements in 3rd subselect

Comment: ya somehow i missed it

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Select them using subqueries:

```
SELECT
    KnownUsers=(SELECT  COUNT(distinct GroupUserID) from Table A WHERE ...),
    UnKnownUsers=(SELECT  COUNT(distinct GroupUserID) from TableB  WHERE (a   different condition)),
    Managers=(SELECT  COUNT(distinct ManagerID) from TableX  WHERE (condition)),
    TeamLeads=(SELECT  COUNT(distinct LeadID) from TableX  WHERE (condition));
```

Comment: I think you should separate the elements in 3rd subselect

Comment: @etsa Oh right :) didn't see that two columns were selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from 
(
    select COUNT(1) TotalRecord,'KnownUsers' as Users from TableA 
    union all
    select COUNT(1) TotalRecord,'UnKnownUsers' as Users from TableB 
    union all
    select COUNT(1) TotalRecord,'TeamLeads' as Users from TableX
    union all
    select COUNT(1) TotalRecord,'Managers' as Users from TableX
)
 UserDetails
pivot
(
  sum(TotalRecord)
  for Users in ([KnownUsers], [UnKnownUsers], [TeamLeads], [Managers])
) piv;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this it would be fast as compare of using subquery.

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ManagerID) AS Managers ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT LeadID) AS TeamLeads ,
        Tmp.KnownUsers ,
        Tmp1.UnKnownUsers
FROM    TableX
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    COUNT(DISTINCT GroupUserID) AS KnownUsers
                      FROM      TableA
                      WHERE (Condition)
                    ) Tmp
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    COUNT(DISTINCT GroupUserID) AS UnKnownUsers
                      FROM      TableB
                      WHERE (a different condtion)
                    ) Tmp1
WHERE (TableXCondition)
```